# How to prevent alert dialog from appearing when some condition is fulfilled?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

```
 //NotificationPermission Dialog
private void notificationPermissionDialog(){
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("Do you want to Enable Notifications?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        savePermissionInPreferences("Yes");
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        savePermissionInPreferences("No");
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

//Save Notification Permission in Preferences
private void savePermissionInPreferences(String isNotificationAllowed){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PermissionPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("isNotificationAllowed", isNotificationAllowed);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I have created a dialogue which appears when fragment is opened and ask for permission if I click on NO its value is saved in shared preference for preventing it to appear again but when I replace my fragment in same activity dialogue appears again and again. Please anyone can guide me through it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do something like below

```
private void notificationPermissionDialog(){

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PermissionPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//Add these
String permission = sharedPreferences.getString("isNotificationAllowed", "");

//Add this line
if(!permission == "No"){ 
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("Do you want to Enable Notifications?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    savePermissionInPreferences("Yes");
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    savePermissionInPreferences("No");
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
}
}

//Save Notification Permission in Preferences
private void savePermissionInPreferences(String isNotificationAllowed){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PermissionPref", 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("isNotificationAllowed", isNotificationAllowed);
    editor.apply();
}
```

If the user selected no to the Alert Dialog it wont appear again.